# Fullpage.js after refresh it doesn't scroll down issue

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am using this js plugin: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js
This is my js:

```
$('.cms-index-index .std').fullpage({
            css3: true,
            scrollingSpeed: 1000,
            responsiveWidth: 650,
            anchors: ['s0','s1','s2'],
 });
```

and this is part of the generated html:

```
<div data-anchor="s0" style="height: 633px;" id="section0" class="section fp-section fp-table"><div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:633px;">
...
</div>
<div data-anchor="s1" style="height: 633px;" id="section1" class="section fp-section fp-table"><div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:633px;">
...
</div>
```

My problem is when i refresh mypage it does not scroll down to s1 if my url is mypage.com/#s1. If i changed it to s0 and hit the enter it works. But if a open a new tab and put my url there, it doesn't. What am i doing wrong? thx

Comment: Do you get any JS errors when you load the page and it fails? Also you do not need the `,` on anchors. Also when are you calling `fullpage`? is it inside a `$(document).ready`? It could be that the code is trying to run before the section is there.

Comment: it is inside document ready. and the "," i removed it. And no erros in the console

Comment: It was a script beforeunload in js , i removed it and it works.thx for the idea

Comment: You will need to provide a reproduction of the issue for us to help you. It looks like you are missing something.

Comment: @Chester so have you fixed this now?